# How easy is it to target a subnet behind a router?

Tags: network, router

I would like to know how difficult it would be for an attacker to reach a subnet behind a router once he gained access to the router. For example, the router would be on 200.1.1.3 and the subnet on 200.1.1.4

Comment: This needs some clarity, are you asking how difficult it would be to communicate to hosts on a subnet defined by the router when you have console access to said router?

Comment: The subnet is created by another device not the original router but yes I want to know how easy it is for someone without or with access to the router to access the local subnet

Comment: I'm thinking there is a lot of basic networking knowledge that would be required to modify the question before an answer can be given. And since you change what you are asking in a comment, it gets more confusing. Here's the question: is the router performing NAT? And did you mean to give the IP range a publicly routable range?